# If new Date is less than date stored in variable

Tags: javascript, date-comparison

I am just wondering how I can compare a date with the following code:

```
var today = new Date();
```

Outputs the current day like so:

```
Wed Feb 24 2016 12:02:34 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)
```

However if I have a variable containing a string like so:

```
var end = "Tue Mar 1 2016 00.00.00 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)";
```

I am unable to compare these two variables in an if statement using the greater than operator because the `end` variable is a string.

So I am just wondering how I can compare a set date in a variable with my today variable?

Thanks, Nick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [timestamp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime) of the date, instead of the string representation.

```
var today = new Date();
console.log(today.getTime());
```

That's an integer and you can compare two of those. Keep in mind that this is a milliseconds timestamp, and not a seconds one, if you want to compare it with timestamps from other sources.

Note: There's also the option to parse back from the string representation of the time to Date object, but that depends a lot on the format the string was composed in (and possibly the JS client) and it may not always work. I recommend to only work with numeric timestamps if you plan on comparing times.

Comment: you'll need to convert the variable end to a date and then compare them as Date("end variable string")

Comment: @TaranJ See the comment I left to Matt's answer to understand why that may be a bad idea.

Comment: Yep, still you'll need to convert the string to Date Object and then obtain its timestamp using getTime

Comment: How could you compare this to the `end` date without using a date object though? As @TaranJ said, you would still need to do `getTime()`

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new date object with your stored date and compare them.

```
var today = new Date();

//Edited date slightly to make it fit javascript date format
var end = new Date("Thu Mar 01 2001 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT)");
```

For example

```
if(today > end){
    //do something
}
```

Comment: I also wanted to suggest to try this, but for me, at least, parsing that date in that format does not succeed, so it might be platform dependent.

Comment: @AlinPurcaru, I copied OPs date which was invalid. Try again.

Comment: Invalid against what? You can't pass this date to the `Date` constructor, but this doesn't make it invalid. "Feb 30" is an invalid date.

Comment: @Pavlo good point. I've edited my answer to be more clear on what I meant.